# How to keep date of adding items into shopping basket?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a shopping basket which keeps different items, I need to keep the date and time of adding each product into shopping basket. I have a solution for it but not sure if there is any other efficient method to do it. As shown blew solution is to create an intermediary class called CusItem to keep items and their addDate.

**ShoppingBasket.java**

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingBasket implements Serializable{

   public List <CusItem> items;
   private Long Id;

   @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   public List <CusItem> getItems(){
       reutnr items;
   }
```

**CusItem.java**

```
@Entity
public class CusItem {
     private Long Id;
     private Item item;
     private Date addDate;

     ......
}
```

**Item.java**

```
@Entity
public class Item{
     private Long Id;
     private String name;
     private Double price;

     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all based on your modeling against your project requirement. Probably you need to have timetamp in your `ShoppingBasket` to know when it is initiated and when it is checked out.

```
@Entity
public class ShoppingBasket implements Serializable{

   public List <BasketLineItem> items;
   private Long Id;
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date beginTime;
   @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   private Date endTime;
   ...
}
```

As you planned if you need to have timestamp for each basket line time to know when it is added, your choice is correct.

```
@Entity
public class BasketLineItem {
     private Long Id;
     private Item item;
     private Date addedDate;
     ......
}
```